# what is the best way to use managed identities feature for AKS cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, dns, rbac, azure-aks, azure-managed-identity

through my testing some new features for AKS clusters i want to enable managed identities feature for my azure k8s cluster, can anyone just simply tell me what the main benefit to use this ? and do i need in this way an externel DNS zone ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Currently, an Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster (specifically,
>   the Kubernetes cloud provider) requires a service principal to create
>   additional resources like load balancers and managed disks in Azure.
>   Either you must provide a service principal or AKS creates one on your
>   behalf. Service principals typically have an expiration date. Clusters
>   eventually reach a state in which the service principal must be
>   renewed to keep the cluster working. Managing service principals adds
>   complexity.
>
> Managed identities are essentially a wrapper around service
>   principals, and make their management simpler. To learn more, read
>   about managed identities for Azure resources.
>
> AKS creates two managed identities:
>
> System-assigned managed identity: The identity that the Kubernetes
>   cloud provider uses to create Azure resources on behalf of the user.
>   The life cycle of the system-assigned identity is tied to that of the
>   cluster. The identity is deleted when the cluster is deleted.
>   User-assigned managed identity: The identity that's used for
>   authorization in the cluster. For example, the user-assigned identity
>   is used to authorize AKS to use Azure Container Registries (ACRs), or
>   to authorize the kubelet to get metadata from Azure. Add-ons also
>   authenticate using a managed identity. For each add-on, a managed
>   identity is created by AKS and lasts for the life of the add-on. For
>   creating and using your own VNet, static IP address, or attached Azure
>   disk where the resources are outside of the MC_* resource group, use
>   the PrincipalID of the cluster to perform a role assignment. For more
>   information on role assignment, see Delegate access to other Azure
>   resources.

in short - to ease management